# hasicorp vault with existing Azure disk

Tags: azure-aks, hashicorp-vault, argocd

I am installing **hashicorp vault** by **helm chart** using **Argocd** on AKS and I can't edit the Values file to mount its data into the existing Azure disk so how to configure it to use my **Azure disk**?

I want to do this because if the cluster goes down so I can have my secrets saved

I tried to change the parameters of persistent volume while installing the vault but I didn't figure out how to put the yaml syntax in one line and I don't know if it will run or not

Answer (score 0):

You can take a snapshot from my vault but by editing its backend
using raft then run this command:

```
vault operator raft snapshot save ./vaultsnapshot.snap
```

and to restore the snapshot in another vault:

```
vault operator raft snapshot restore ./vaultsnapshot.snap
```

Note: when you restore the snapshot the vault will be sealed. To unseal it you should use key from the vault that you take the snapshot from.